# Visual Studio 2015 Community crash without error or any dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crash, vs-community-edition

i just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community and want to create a Project. But i can't.... because everytime i try to hit the OK button in the New Project window, VS crashes without an error or anything. It just shutdowns.

Is there anyway i can provide you an error code or something that would even help me to google for the problem?

Greetings
Hagen

Answer (score 0):

You can use comment in question

[Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 always crashes in Windows 10 if swithed to Visual FoxPro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164048/microsoft-visual-studio-community-2015-always-crashes-in-windows-10-if-swithed-t/)

to create dump file, examine this dump file using windbg and find faulting code.

Howefully yuo can determine line number causing crash and look into source code for this line.
This gives the idea about fixing the issue.