# Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 always crashes in Windows 10 if swithed to Visual FoxPro

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crash, visual-foxpro, vs-community-edition

If Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 community edition IDE is opened in Windows 10 and  Microsoft Visal Foxpro IDE is in foreground,

after few seconds Visual Studio crashes with

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 stopped working
```

message.

How to fix this ? It is not possible to use Microsoft Visal FoxPro IDE is Visual Studio is opened.

After that in shows collection information for a long time but no more information is given.
After it is restared, it offers to recovers files.
If FixPro IDE is brought to foreground, it crashed again and so on.

In Windows 7 boths ides worked.

Posted also in http://forums.asp.net/p/2098546/6062971.aspx

Update

Below is output from x86 windbg.exe
It looks like System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars call in VS method causes crash.
Is this related to my locale ?
I think only english characters are used in file and path names accessed by both IDE-s.

Why line numbers are not displayed ?
Debugging/Symbols/Use Microsoft Symber Servers is checked in Visual Studio,
All modules, unless excluded radio box is selected and no modules are excluded.

How to find line number in CheckInvalidPathChars  source code which causes exception ?

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\LocalDumps\devenv.exe.7652.dmp]
User Mini Dump File with Full Memory: Only application data is available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 10586 MP (8 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Built by: 10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Sun Jul  3 17:58:41.000 2016 (UTC + 3:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 2:25:20.731
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:07:52.000
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.................................
Loading unloaded module list
...............
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(1de4.1014): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first/second chance not available)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000003 edi=00000003
eip=7743718c esp=330ee0f8 ebp=330ee288 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc:
7743718c c21400          ret     14h
0:068> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Core.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for PresentationCore.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for WindowsBase.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.Build.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for nativrd2.dll - 
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.Management.Automation.ni.dll
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.ni.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for mscordbi.dll - 

DUMP_CLASS: 2

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
eax=330eede8 ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=330eeea8 edi=00000001
eip=7712dae8 esp=330eede8 ebp=330eee40 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48:
7712dae8 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h] ss:002b:330eee3c=872f3008
Resetting default scope

FAULTING_IP: 
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+48
7712dae8 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 7712dae8 (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x00000048)
   ExceptionCode: e0434352 (CLR exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000001
NumberParameters: 5
   Parameter[0]: 80070057
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
   Parameter[2]: 00000000
   Parameter[3]: 00000000
   Parameter[4]: 6cd80000

PROCESS_NAME:  devenv.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xe0434352 - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80070057 (2147942487) - The parameter is incorrect.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80070057

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  80070057

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER3:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER4: 0

WATSON_BKT_PROCSTAMP:  57685d85

WATSON_BKT_PROCVER:  14.0.25420.1

PROCESS_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2015

WATSON_BKT_MODULE:  KERNELBASE.dll

WATSON_BKT_MODSTAMP:  571afb9a

WATSON_BKT_MODOFFSET:  bdae8

WATSON_BKT_MODVER:  10.0.10586.306

MODULE_VER_PRODUCT:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)

MODLIST_WITH_TSCHKSUM_HASH:  4fcd781d45a1334d9bcf598acb3135d540e69ef0

MODLIST_SHA1_HASH:  a0fd1d4cab671d86ea9b9d7967795f680101df97

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

SUITE_MASK:  272

DUMP_FLAGS:  8000c07

DUMP_TYPE:  0

APP:  devenv.exe

MISSING_CLR_SYMBOL: 0

MANAGED_EXCEPTION_HRESULT: 80070057

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DELL2

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  07-03-2016 18:16:32.0068

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10586.567 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

MANAGED_THREAD_ID: 1014

MANAGED_EXCEPTION_ADDRESS: 36697728

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 6ce8a701 to 7712dae8

THREAD_ATTRIBUTES: 
FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  7b898fe56a64f5be9b4f1219f22e997dac66cbc4

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  1211f347092e8a4415eb763a6305ba8f87471780

OS_LOCALE:  ETI

PROBLEM_CLASSES: 



CLR_EXCEPTION
    Tid    [0x44]
    Frame  [0x00]




    String [System.ArgumentException]
    Failure Bucketing
    Data Bucketing



FINALIZER
    Tid    [0x1014]
    Frame  [0x0d]: clr!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer
    Failure Bucketing



NOSOS
    Tid    [0x1014]
    Failure Bucketing


BUGCHECK_STR:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException

STACK_TEXT:  
330eefac 66e3c13d mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars+0xb3cfbd
330eefbc 663ab5c6 mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.GetFileName+0x16
330eefd4 65d2112b system_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern+0xf
330eefe8 65d2118e system_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs+0x16
330ef000 6580f251 system_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged+0x275
330ef060 66372134 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback+0x70


STACK_COMMAND:  !sos.pe 0x36697728 ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  9e580844edc1c536a492e0ccea2cdd390265f467

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mscorlib_ni+e3c13d
66e3c13d cc              int     3

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  8dcccccc

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars+e3c13d

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: mscorlib_ni

IMAGE_NAME:  mscorlib.ni.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  570c5040

BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException_mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars+e3c13d

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException_mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars+e3c13d

BUCKET_ID_OFFSET:  e3c13d

BUCKET_ID_MODULE_STR:  mscorlib_ni

BUCKET_ID_MODTIMEDATESTAMP:  570c5040

BUCKET_ID_MODCHECKSUM:  1154df8

BUCKET_ID_MODVER_STR:  4.6.1080.0

BUCKET_ID_PREFIX_STR:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException_

FAILURE_PROBLEM_CLASS:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException

FAILURE_EXCEPTION_CODE:  80070057

FAILURE_IMAGE_NAME:  mscorlib.ni.dll

FAILURE_FUNCTION_NAME:  System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars

BUCKET_ID_FUNCTION_STR:  System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars

FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  mscorlib.ni.dll!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  CLR_EXCEPTION_FINALIZER_NOSOS_System.ArgumentException_80070057_mscorlib.ni.dll!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/devenv.exe/14.0.25420.1/57685d85/KERNELBASE.dll/10.0.10586.306/571afb9a/80070057/000bdae8.htm?Retriage=1

TARGET_TIME:  2016-07-03T14:58:41.000Z

OSBUILD:  10586

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x86

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt SingleUserTS

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2015-10-30 04:46:21

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  151029-1700

BUILDLAB_STR:  th2_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.10586.0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 6952

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:clr_exception_finalizer_nosos_system.argumentexception_80070057_mscorlib.ni.dll!system.io.path.checkinvalidpathchars

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {9ac34ec0-80d5-6afc-db16-24c08255921b}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Update2

Output from sos.pe after that:

```
0:068> !sos.pe 0x36697728
Exception object: 36697728
Exception type:   System.ArgumentException
Message:          Illegal characters in path.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    330EEFAC 66E3C13D mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(System.String, Boolean)+0xb3cfbd
    330EEFBC 663AB5C6 mscorlib_ni!System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.String)+0x16
    330EEFD4 65D2112B System_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern(System.String)+0xf
    330EEFE8 65D2118E System_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(Int32, System.String)+0x16
    330EF000 6580F251 System_ni!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x275
    330EF060 66372134 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x70

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80070057
```

Update3.

Visual Studio Shows Stack trace with parameter values:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(string path, bool checkAdditional)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string path = "andmed\\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")   Unknown
System.dll!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.MatchPattern(string relativePath)    Unknown
System.dll!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(int action = 3, string name = "andmed\\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")  Unknown
System.dll!System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.CompletionStatusChanged(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer = 0x1e9bc584)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(uint errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP) Unknown
```

Comment: capture a crash dump of VS (import this file: dropbox.com/s/kmtkd1h7ans24v5/WER_VS_full.reg?dl=0 to configure WER to generate a dump: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx). After VS crashes, you can see a dmp in C:\localdumps, now import this reg to stop dmp creation: dropbox.com/s/vhj02wpza12bvwj/WER_VS_full_uninstall.reg?dl=0). Open the dmp in Windbg.exe (part of Windows SDK/Debugging Tools), setup symbols (support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and run !analyze -v. Now look if you can see at which part VS crashes.

Comment: @magicandre  I updated question and added windbg output. It looks like System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars call in VS causes crash. How to find line in source code where crach occurs? How to fix the issue?

Comment: run the offered command **!sos.pe 0x36697728** to dump the exception

Comment: @magicandre1981  I ran this command and updated question with result

Comment: play a bit with the dumpstack command, maybe this helps to see more details: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-14-WinDbg-SOS if not, run processmonitor in background, after VS crashed, go back to procmon, stop logging and look in the list when werfault shows up. Now scroll up to look for devenv.exe file operations and the result. if you see any errors look at the property to see which path is accessed.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Visual Studio shows stack trace with parameter values. I updated with result. It looks like VS tries to use invalid directory name `"andmed\\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"`   FoxPro project contains subdirectory `andmed` . It looks like VS looks into FoxPro directory and adds zeroes to end. How to fix ?

Comment: @magicandre1981 How to change and re-compile FileSystemWatcher or GetFileName in mscorlib so that exception is not thrown. Based in my knowledge .NET is open source so it may be possible to fix them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you are saying. I have VFP, VS 2015 Community, SSMS, PostgreSQL PgAdmin all open and working happily under windows 10 pro. The only thing I did different is to install windows 10 from scratch instead of upgrading (on our machines, upgrading didn't work at some machines, worked with faults on some, and worked well on some. Installation from scratch, although having problems on some of the machines -such as not recognizing PCIe SSD, no matter that we used the latest drivers-, worked much better).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Create TrueCrypt 7.1a drive and put VS and VFP projects into this drive. After switching to VFP VS crashes always.

Comment: I don't have truecrypt nor a desire to install it.

Comment: TC 7.1a was latest version before it was killed since it cannot decrypted by NSA. It is free and open source. You can still find it in internet or I can sent it to you.

Comment: the truecrypt development is stopped so decrypt the container/drive and use the buildin bitlocker or VeryCrypt. Look if the issue is fixed are removing truecrypt

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to encrypt my drive with TC, bitlocker or anything else.

Comment: @magicandre1981 If windows private key is lost Bitlocked data cannot decrypted. Bitlocker can decrypted by NSA. TC may still be better than VeraCrypt (http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72249/is-there-a-reason-to-use-truecrypt-over-veracrypt ). I'm probably forced to switch to VeraCrypt due to this issue. It looks like using TC+VFP broadcasts invalid name in windows directory changed event which is listened by VS

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm using PostgreSQL ODBC driver with VFP9 . VFP application frequently crashes with C5 exception in REPORT line if previewing report with REPORT PREVIEW command (old non-listener report engine is used). Have you encountered such issue ?

Comment: No, I haven't seen such a thing with postgreSQL (PostgreSQL is the best SQL series database I have ever seen). However, I have seen C5 errors with some printer drivers (particularly HP and Epson printers). Using windows shipped driver instead of HP drivers fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Printer drivers cause C94 exception in VFP. Sending fonts as bitmaps and disabling print optimization helps. Maybe changing windows locale to US also helps.

Comment: does removing Truecrypt fixes it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes. It seems that VeraCrypt works OK, this issue does not occur in VeraCrypt.

Comment: @Andrus, printer drivers cause c5 as well.

Comment: @CetinBasoz  New psqlODBC driver versions does not return proper error message before logged in. I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212586/how-to-get-proper-error-message-before-logging-in-from-psqlodbc-driver and will post in UT also. Have you encountered this ?

Comment: ok, post your Trecrypt finding as answer, maybe other users also run int the issue and they can find it much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing TrueCrypt with VeraCrypt fixes the issue.